# Is pci express 3.0 backwards compatible?

Tags: pci-express

Is PCI express 3.0 backwards compatible with the other revisions? I read on Wikipedia that this was going to be attempted, but I can't find anywhere this is confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The cards and bus (per card) will operate at the lowest common speed that both support.

[Wikipedia: PCI Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_3.0) mentions `that it would be backwards compatible with existing PCIe implementations`.

[PCIe 3.0 Base Spec](http://www.pcisig.com/specifications/pciexpress/base3/) §4.2.2 elaborates:

> For backwards compatibility, the Link
>   initially trains to L0 at the 2.5 GT/s data rate using 8b/10b encoding as described in Section 4.2.1,
>   then when the data rate is changed to 8.0 GT/s or higher, 128b/130b encoding is used.

Comment: Cool, do you have a source for this information? I can not seem to find it anywhere...